Image strip not using alpha channel
im using a image strip that uses the alpha channel (transparency) but the transparency is black and opaque. i have the blend mode set to alpha over and have the alpha color management set to straight. here are my settings that maybe related to this issue 



Could you please show the image sequence (or one image) how the transparency is supposed to look like, what it looks like in the sequencer and what you have below the strip that should be showing through the transparency? Also show the strips in the editor?

Hi, Bludus .. I  have to agree with @Gordon, here.. anything you can think of, please,  that can help us help you.

@GordonBrinkmann i added another image, the black part of the preview is supposed to be transparent but it is not.

I think it would be simpler if you could pack the original image file you are using in your 'blend and share your file with us . AFAIK the settings you have should work for a transparent image, unless the image doesn't have anything to show transparent, or there's something else in the blend file preventing you to see transparency.

@Bludus You have made the strips so thin that I see any labels on it... but it looks to me as if the image sequence is at the bottom of the stack. So there is nothing to see below the transparent gap. Therefore it shows black (since video files - with very few exceptions - do not allow transparent backgrounds).

@GordonBrinkmann i did add another image strip to the bottom layer and added the one i showed on top and the alpha channel didnt work

@Bludus Well, in the screenshot the strip is in channel 1 and there is nothing below it. I also cannot see if the alpha channel or the image settings are okay so it is probably best if you would upload the file.
